# cannot burn dvd's

Tags: boot, mount, fstab, dvd, burning

I cannot burn DVDs with Ubuntu Gnome 14.04. Here's what I have done to troubleshoot why this is happening:

```
david@EvilGenius:~$ ls -l /dev/sr0
brw-rw----+ 1 root cdrom 11, 0 Sep  7 13:40 /dev/sr0
david@EvilGenius:~$ sudo mount /dev/sr0 /tmp/dvd
mount: mount point /tmp/dvd does not exist
david@EvilGenius:~$ sudo mount /dev/sr0 /dvd
mount: mount point /dvd does not exist
david@EvilGenius:~$ sudo mount /dev/sr0
mount: can't find /dev/sr0 in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
david@EvilGenius:~$ sudo -i
root@EvilGenius:~# gedit /etc/fstab
root@EvilGenius:~# gedit /etc/mtab
root@EvilGenius:~# eject /dev/sr0
eject: unable to eject, last error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
root@EvilGenius:~#
```

I have looked into fstab and mtab folders and found no listing of my device. My device will read only. And it does that without any problems. However, the device is a rewrite-able with Lightscribe capability. Does anyone here have a few suggestions to get this device working right?